# How to make "share nearby" work on win10?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, android

According to this link

https://www.xda-developers.com/androids-nearby-share-now-works-windows-google-chrome/

there is an experimental option that enable `Share Nearby` between Android device and Win10. I went through all the steps, enabled `chrome://flags` `"Nearby Sharing” flag`, then I restarted chrome browser but when I try to open `chrome://nearby` link I got a message like this link is unreachable.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, did you note that the article points out that the feature isn't yet working in stable Chrome releases? Unless you're on the Dev or Canary pre-release channels for Chrome (or the feature has made it to the Release channel since that article was published), it is known to not work. This seems most in line with your experience.

Second, do you have Bluetooth on your Win10 PC, and is it enabled? The feature relies on Bluetooth, and while most laptops and tablets have it, most desktops do not. Even if you have the hardware for it, it might be disabled either in the firmware or in the OS, or not working due to not having the right driver installed (though Win10 does include built-in drivers for all the common Bluetooth hardware).

Comment: Yes, I have a bluetooth as a toggle I use it for connect to my headset and mouse, so it works (at least for connection to these devices). But as you mentioned about Dev or Canary channels for Chrome I just now downloaded it - https://www.google.com/chrome/canary/thank-you.html?statcb=1&installdataindex=empty&defaultbrowser=0 , but in this canary channel if I open chrome://flags there isn't flag for sharing nearby and if I try to open this page chrome://nearby I got the same message `unreachable`.

Comment: Hmm, I'd recommend looking for more info from Google about the feature, then. Not everything in the pre-release channels eventually gets released; sometimes it's pulled temporarily to fix issues, or permanently if there's a problem with the feature. The article you linked was published months ago, which is a long time in terms of Chrome releases.